# Why can't variable names be deallocated for future use?

Tags: variables, naming, strong-typing

Why don't strongly typed programming languages, like the C family, for example, allow you to deallocate a variable name completely? That is, let's say you have a variable `int x = 5`. Why is there no statement of code like `remove x` or `deallocateName x` so that you can assign x later on to be something else, possibly some other type, like `string x = "Hello"`? My guess is that because it relates to these languages being compiled rather than interpreted (like Ruby or Python, for example, where you can assign the same variable to different types) , or maybe because that would defeat the *strictly-typed* philosophy overall.

Comment: Code should be written to be readable by humans for maintenance purpose so given that each variable has a different purpose, it should have a different name... You could limit the scope of a variable name (in many languages) by using additional scopes: `{ int x = 5; }{ string x = "Hello"; }`. A variable end at the closing braket so removing a variable would only hide and make code harder to understand and debug.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes I already know this, but assume the following code: ```Object[] things = {person, dog, cat, car}``` where every element has its own type. You could want to make a variable called ```currentElement``` and instead of assigning it to a general type and using casting or using generics, you may want to deallocate the name ```currentElement``` and reassign it, for example. I know it may sound unnecessary, but it can sometimes make the code clearer to read.

Comment: Also, a variable with the same name can be assigned different types as well in other languages like weak typed ones, so it can serve different purposes while having the same name.